# inflating all views in layout finished event

Tags: android, events, layout

I want to know if there is an event that fires when all views in layout are inflated,I know about addOnGlobalLayoutListener method but it works only for one view ,I need an event for all views in a layout.

Comment: In a fragment or activity?

Comment: I need it for an activity

Answer (score 2):

Try using [onFinishInflate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onFinishInflate%28%29) in your content view. You're gonna have to extend the layout class you are using, though.